# df.groupby(...).apply(...) function in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, dask

I was using Python `dask` to process a large csv panel data set (15+GB), and I needed to conduct a `groupby(...).apply(...)` function  to delete the last observations for each stock in each day. My dataset looks like

```
 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff 
  VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01     0:07     
  VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03     0:52     
  VOD      01-01   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-01   10:15    0.01     0:10     
  VOD      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  VOD      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  VOD      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
  ...       ...     ...     ....     ...
  BAT      01-01    13:05   0.04    10:02
  BAT      01-02    9:07    0.05     0:03
  BAT      01-02    9:10    0.06     0:04
  ...       ...     ...     ....     ...
```

If the dataframe was in pandas then this can be done by

`df_new=df_have.groupby(['stock','date'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])`

This code works well for pandas df. However, I could not execute this code in dask dataframe. I have made the following attempts.

`ddf_new=ddf_have.groupby(['stock','date']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1]).compute()`

or

`ddf_new=ddf_have.groupby(['stock','date']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1],  meta=('stock' : 'f8')).compute()`

or

`ddf_new=ddf_have.groupby(['stock','date']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1],  meta=meta).compute()`

Unfortunately, none of them worked. Can anyone help me to get the right code for dask dataframe ? THX

Comment: If you don't run `compute` you're not performing anything but creating a graph. The golden rule with dask is that if the operation runs in pandas you don't need to switch to dask. Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai   thanks. I've added a quick example.

Comment: About performances: is your data stored on a single `CSV` file?

Comment: @rpanai  yeah...............

Answer (score 2):

I think that for your specific case the problem is the `meta` you are assigning. This should work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01',
                      end='2019-12-31',
                      freq='5T')

out = []
for stock in list("abcdefgh"):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"stock":[stock]*len(dates),
                       "date":dates,
                       "spread":np.random.randn(len(dates))})
    df["time_diff"] = df["date"].diff().shift(-1)
    df["time"] = df["date"].dt.time.astype(str)
    df["date"] = df["date"].dt.date.astype(str)
    out.append(df)
df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)

del out

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)

out = ddf.groupby(['stock','date']).apply(lambda x: x[:-1],
                                          meta={"stock":"str",
                                                "date":"str",
                                                "spread":"f8",
                                                "time_diff":"str",
                                                "time":"str"})
out = out.compute().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you can nicely partitions your file by stock-day and save in `to_parquet` you can have some better performance as you can use `map_partitions` instead of `apply`.

Comment: thanks for replying.  I see that you have defined each column in pandas dataframe before converting it to dask. I used dd.read_csv to import data to dask dataframe at the beginning with each column defined.   i tried your code and I still could not get output.   ValueError: Key 2018-01-01 00:00:00 not in level Index.

Comment: I was just creating a `df`. If you use `df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)` and then `ddf =  dd.read_csv("out.csv")` it's the same as your working case.

Comment: This timestamp `2018-01-01 00:00:00 ` is not on my example. Do you mind to check the `dtypes` of your dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used `ddf.astype` and i got stock is object, date is object, spread is float64 and time is str.  However, when I tried `meta={"stock":"object",
                                                       "date":"object",
                                                       "spread":"f8",
                                                       "time_diff":"f8",
                                                       "time":"str"}`   , i got     `    The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata    `   .     Ant idea ? Thanks again.

Comment: After quite a few tries, I found I can run code if I groupby single column index without providing `meta`. If I groupby two columns, then I can only run simple syntax such as  `ddf.groupby(['stock','date']).sum() ` .

Comment: @FlyUFalcon this is right. But it works only when you use the same implemented method on one or more columns.